# Determine if a function is in a fractional Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am linearizing a PDE about a solution to obtain linear stability or instability. The space in which my perturbations are plays an important role.

The solution $w$ of the linear problem I am interested in is analytic for $x<0$. Also, it is such that $w, w'$, and $w''$ behave as $e^{x}$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$, $w\sim |x|^p$ (for some positive $p$) as $x\rightarrow 0^-$, and $w=0$ for $x>0$.

In other words, $w, w'$ and $w''$ go to zero exponentially fast at $x=-\infty$, goes to zero as $|x|^p$ at $x=0$ from the left, and is zero for $x>0$.

I do not have an explicit expression for the solution.

For what value of $p$ is $w$ in $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$, for some $s>3/2$?

A toy example would be $w=e^x-e^{2x}$ for $x\leq 0$ and $w=0$ for $x>0$. One can check that this is in $H^s(\mathbb{R})$ for $s<3/2$. I thus supect that in the general case, $w\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$ for $s\geq 3/2$ only for $p>1$.

Comment: Did you mean $w \sim |x|^p$ as $x \to 0^-$?

Comment: Yes, I made the change. Thank you.

Comment: You need much more information about $w$. The growth rates help with integrability, but the index $s$ is a measure of smoothness.

Comment: Echoing @UmbertoP.'s comment, for example $\sin(e^{x^2})e^{-|x|}$ goes to $0$ exponentially to the left, but its derivative blows up... so it'll not be in any good Sobolev space. (The patching at $0$ is not the problem.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I added the fact that $w'$ and $w''$ also behave as $e^x$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ and also that $w$ is an analytic function for $x<0$. These properties follow from the linear system I am solving.

Comment: When you talk about the derivatives, are they the derivatives in the classical or the distributional sense ?

Comment: It's in the classical sense. The solution is analytical for $x<0$.

Comment: I am not sure about what your hypothesis at 0 is... Do we have that  $w $, $w'$ and $w''$ all go to 0 when $x $ goes to 0 ? In this case, it works :

Comment: So, considering that all the functions ($w $, $w'$ and $w''$) are continuons, $w $ is $C^2$ because it is the integral of $w'$ from $- \infty $ to $x $ on $\mathbb {R} ^-$ , and so up to 0 by continuity, and then on $\mathbb {R}^+$ because everything is 0 there. Thus, by doing the same for $w'$, $w $ is in facture  $C^2$, so its distributional derivatives are classical derivatives, that have squares that are integrable. (Because the functions are continuous, $0$ at  $+ \infty $ and bounded by $exp (x) $ multiplied by a constant at $- \infty $). So $w \in H^2 ( \mathbb{R})$, for every $p$.

Comment: @paul If $0<p<1$ for example, then the first derivative $w'$ is singular at 0. In that case, $w$ is not in $H^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pardon me for putting this all onto the positive real axis... since otherwise I would commit sign errors every few seconds.

To my mind, the function $f_s(x)$ which is $x^se^-x$ on $x>0$ and is $0$ to the left, decides this issue. Namely, you can subtract a multiple of this from your function, to have something whose derivatives decay very well and vanish to one higher order at $0$. It's Fourier transform is explicit (by various means).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!